# iterate through lis, if text contains, .click();

Tags: javascript

I am trying the below but "`World`" is failing: In the console it's resolving as `false` after my or operator.

```
   var liz = document.querySelectorAll(".__item--selected")[0];

      if(liz.innerHTML.indexOf("SkyFall" || "World") !== -1) {
        custom= liz.title;
        console.log("found " + custom);
      } else  { ....... }
```

**Part 2:**

I would like to iterate through a list of `li`s and `click();` the `li` that has the matching `innerText` of my `custom` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expressions via the [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method:

```js
var liz = document.querySelectorAll(".__item--selected")[0];

      if( liz.innerHTML.match(/SkyFall|World/) ) {
        custom= liz.title;
        console.log("found " + custom);
      } else  { ....... }
```

---

**Note:** Also, take into consideration the notes by @Scott Marcus and whether you really want to look into the HTML or the textContent of the element.

---

*P.S. Maximum Overdrive was hell of a movie! :P*

Answer (score 2):

An `if` condition must be complete. You have to write both test conditions out in full.

Also, `document.querySelectorAll(".__item--selected")[0]` doesn't make sense. If you know you want the first match, use `.querySelector()`.

Additionally, if you are testing for plain text and not HTML, don't use `.innerHTML`, use `.textContent`.

```
var liz = document.querySelector(".__item--selected");

if(liz.textContent.indexOf("SkyFall") !== -1 || liz.textContent.indexOf("World") !== -1) {
    custom= liz.title;
    console.log("found " + custom);
} else  { ....... }
```